# Laravel Eloquent whereHas relationship

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

My project framework is laravel 10 and database is postgres. I am trying to fetch the user data based on some filter condition of franchise and sub franchise but getting an error as mentioned below:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table \"main_franchise\"\nLINE 1: ...ere \"users\".\"id\" = \"user_franchise\".\"user_id\" and \"main_fran...\n
```

I tried using the whereHas relationship but it returns error. Any suggesstion on where I made the mistake will be very grateful

**UserController**

```
$users = User::with(['user_main_franchise', 'user_sub_franchise'])
->when(isset($filter['main_franchise']), function ($query) use ($filter) {
    $query->whereHas('user_main_franchise', function ($q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('main_franchise.id', $filter['main_franchise']['id']);
    });
})
->when(isset($filter['sub_franchise']), function ($query) use ($filter) {
    $query->whereHas('user_sub_franchise', function ($q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('sub_franchise.id', $filter['sub_franchise']['id']);
    });
})
->paginate(10);
```

**User model relatioship**

```
public function user_main_franchise()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(MainFranchise::class, 'user_franchise', 'user_id', 'main_franchise_id');
}

public function user_sub_franchise()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubFranchise::class, 'user_franchise', 'user_id', 'sub_franchise_id');
}
```

**user_franchise database**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFbCA.png)

Comment: first can you remove this from yuou query then try ->when(isset($filter['sub_franchise']), function ($query) use ($filter) {
    $query->whereHas('user_sub_franchise', function ($q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('sub_franchise.id', $filter['sub_franchise']['id']);
    });
})

Comment: The error suggests that the MainFranchise class doesn't have a table defined. Not sure ,can you also add the MainFranchise and SubFranchise Model and schema?

Comment: @UmerFayyaz I have done some changes in the code and it is working fine, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not with respect to relationship.     ->where('sub_franchise.id', $filter['sub_franchise']['id']);
    to
    ->where('user_franchise.sub_franchise_id', $filter['sub_franchise']['id']);  
    and 
    -> where('main_franchise.id', $filter['main_franchise']['id']);
    to
    -> where('user_franchise.main_franchise_id', $filter['main_franchise']['id']);

Comment: @Web22 yes i think it is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You should write table name on where clause. You wrote incorrect table name.
Try this:

```
$users = User::with(['user_main_franchise', 'user_sub_franchise'])
->when(isset($filter['main_franchise']), function ($query) use ($filter) {
    $query->whereHas('user_main_franchise', function ($q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('main_franchise_id', $filter['main_franchise']['id']);
    });
})
->when(isset($filter['sub_franchise']), function ($query) use ($filter) {
    $query->whereHas('user_sub_franchise', function ($q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('sub_franchise_id', $filter['sub_franchise']['id']);
    });
})
->paginate(10);
```

For using another table on where clause you should join that table.
In your code you can't use `main_franchise` table because you didn't join it. And I think it is not necessary for you join that table. Because you are using only id and this field values are available already on main_franchise_id and sub_franchise_id columns